# Maven package/install without test (skip tests)

Tags: java, maven

I am trying to package my project. But, it automatically runs the tests previous do performing the packaging. The tests insert some content in the database. This is not what I want, I need to avoid running tests while package the application. Anybody knows how run the package with out test?

Comment: A Unit-Test should consist of the following 4 phases: Initialization, Test, Verification and Teardown. Maybe you should adjust your tests and add an according teardown/cleanup of your database or you should use a separate database instance, not packaged with your jar file, for running your tests on.

Comment: It seems that your tests are "heavy" so you don't  want to execute them. But it's a bad practice. Maybe some frameworks as DBUnit may help you ? Or you can revert database changes at the end of the test?

Answer (score 897, accepted):

Run maven with

```
mvn package -Dmaven.test.skip
```

Comment: thanks for ur immediate reply,am running from eclipse, where i add the command -Dmaven.test.skip=true?

Comment: I've never launched mvn from eclipse, but in the Run Configuration window where you configure maven's targets and profiles, there is a 'Skip Test' checkbox. Maybe that will do the trick.

Comment: according to the [documentation](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/skipping-test.html) that will skip compilation aswell as execution.  You can use -DskipTests to just skip execution.  [This post](http://ericlefevre.net/wordpress/2008/02/21/skipping-tests-with-maven/) also gives some warnings about what versions you can use each flag with

Comment: In Run Configurations window in Eclipse, there is a table with columns as 'Parameter Name' and 'Value'. Entering Parameter name as maven.test.skip and value as true works.

Comment: Since this answer is accepted, I wanted to note a very useful variation from the answer by Chris Beach: `-Dmaven.test.skip.exec`. This will build all the same artifacts, including the test jar, without executing the tests. Otherwise the test jar will be omitted, resulting in partial packaging if that was part of your expected distribution.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I used to do it using ```-DskipTests``` but it does not work anymore, any idea why ?

Comment: Note that [Maven Surefire Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/skipping-test.html) and [Maven Failsafe Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/examples/skipping-test.html) documentation suggests that setting `skipTests` is preferred to setting `maven.test.skip`.

Comment: `-DskipTests` is what you will need for most of the cases. For all other info just check this [this article](https://codepills.com/2020/12/03/how-to-build-with-maven-without-running-tests/)

Comment: mvn install -DskipTests=true

Answer (score 290):

Just provide the command mentioned below, which will ignore executing the test cases (but will compile the test code):

```
mvn package -DskipTests
```

Comment: for me this wouldnt work. I had to use accepted solution instead

Comment: `-DskipTests` did not work for me when I used `mvn clean install -DskipTests`

Comment: Its partially fine as it will not execute test BUT it will comile test classes.....

Comment: For followers, `-DskipTests` is the same as `-Dmaven.test.skip.exec=true`  https://stackoverflow.com/a/21933970/32453 and yes it does compile the tests and not run them (whereas `-Dmaven.test.skip=true` doesn't compile them)

Comment: This one was working for me in maven version 3.8.6 ->
mvn clean package -DskipTests

Comment: This worked me on maven version 3.8.6.

Answer (score 63):

you can add this plugin configuration to your pom if you do not want to set command line arg:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <skipTests>true</skipTests>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: You can no longer run the tests from the command line with this configuration.

Comment: @EmmanuelBourg That can be remedied by following directions in this example http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/skipping-test.html

Comment: corrected link http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/skipping-tests.html

Answer (score 50):

Note that -Dmaven.test.skip prevents Maven building the test-jar artifact.

If you'd like to skip tests but create artifacts as per a normal build use:

```
-Dmaven.test.skip.exec
```

Comment: This was the asnwer I was looking for, works just fine.Thanks.

Comment: How the hell am I supposed to remember that? Why not make a simple obvious and memorable alias like "skipTests"?

Answer (score 43):

If you are trying this in Windows Powershell, you will get this error:

```
[ERROR] Unknown lifecycle phase ".test.skip=true". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format...
```

The reason for this is, in Powershell the "`-`" has special meaning and it is causing problem with maven.

The solution is to prepend it with a backtick (`), like so..

```
mvn `-Dmaven.test.skip=true install
```

Reference: http://kuniganotas.wordpress.com/2011/08/12/invalid-task-test-skiptrue-you-must-specify-a-valid-lifecycle-phase/

Comment: Thanks a lot! Had been facing this issue for a long time now.

Comment: I face this problem in intellij terminal, looks like terminal is pointing to powershell instead of cmd. but this solution saved me

Answer (score 34):

```
<properties>
    <maven.test.skip>true</maven.test.skip>
</properties>
```

is also a way to add in pom file

Answer (score 34):

In Inllij IDEA there is an option also to skip test goal.

[image]

Comment: This works!  I check the cmd it uses: mvn package -DskipTests=true

Answer (score 26):

You can pass the `maven.test.skip` flag as a JVM argument, to skip running tests when the package phase (and the previous ones in the default lifecycle) is run:

```
mvn package -Dmaven.test.skip=true
```

You can also pass the `skipTests` flag alone to the mvn executable. If you want to include this information in your POM, you can create a new profile where you can configure the `maven-surefire-plugin` to [skip tests](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/skipping-test.html).

Answer (score 24):

You only have to provide

```
-Dmaven.test.skip
```

You no longer need to append `=true`.

Answer (score 13):

Answering an old and accepted question here. You can add this in your pom.xml if you want to avoid passing command line argument all the time:

```
  <properties>
    <skipTests>true</skipTests>
  </properties>
```

Answer (score 12):

You can add either `-DskipTests` or `-Dmaven.test.skip=true` to any `mvn` command for skipping tests. In your case it would be like below:

```
mvn package -DskipTests
```

**OR**

```
mvn package -Dmaven.test.skip=true
```

Answer (score 11):

just `mvn clean install -DskipTests`

Answer (score 10):

> you can use any maven goals like **package / clean install**

**Solution: 1 ( package Goal )**

```
mvn package -Dmaven.test.skip
mvn package -Dmaven.test.skip=true
mvn package -DskipTests
```

**Solution: 2 ( clean install goals )**

```
mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip
mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true
mvn clean install -DskipTests
```

**Solution: 3 ( in pom.xml file )**

> you can use **maven-skipping-tests** in pom file and no need to provide
> the attributes like **DskipTests,Dmaven.test.skip**

**Pom.xml**

```
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <maven.test.skip>true</maven.test.skip>
</properties>
```

Later you can use maven command : **mvn clean install/mvn package**

> Reference: https://www.baeldung.com/maven-skipping-tests

Answer (score 7):

A shorthand notation to do maven build and skip tests would be :

mvn clean install -DskipTests

Answer (score 6):

Below two commands are most useful

```
mvn clean package -Dmaven.test.skip=true 
mvn clean package -DskipTests
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Tests should always[1] run before package. If you need to turn off the tests, you're doing something wrong. In other words, you're trying to solve the wrong problem. Figure out what your problem really is, and ask that question. It sounds like it's database-related.

[1] You might skip tests when you need to quickly generate an artifact for local, development use, but in general, creating an artifact should always follow a successful test run.

Comment: I have a similar problem: my applications contains websocket. When i run mvn clean install i end up in an endless test series. Before i force closed it the process has been going on for 3 hours and the messages printed were just about Websocket. Can you please check out my issue to see what am i doing wrong ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54614739/mvn-clean-install-stuck-when-doing-tests-what-am-i-missing

Comment: Rules always have exceptions. If you don't think so, you're wrong.

Answer (score 2):

For maven package without infecting maven test:

```
<properties>
    <maven.test.failure.ignore>true</maven.test.failure.ignore>
</properties>
```

Comment: Thanks, I needed exactly this today.

Answer (score 1):

In Intellij, go to View -> Tool Windows -> choose Maven Projects.
On the Lifecyle dropdown, right-click on package -> choose Create 'your-project [package]'...

Enter this value: `package -Dmaven.test.skip=true -f pom.xml` in the Command line field. Click Apply and a Run Configurations dropdown menu should appear along with your created custom maven command.

Comment: why was this downvoted? I use this everytime I wanted to build my project but skipping tests

Answer (score 1):

Those who don't want to skip the test cases.
just above the main test class comment out or delete annotation:

```
//@SpringBootTest
```

Then when Maven builds an app, it will still run tests inside this class but will not run SpringBoot app, so will not test the connection to DB and the build will be successful.

Answer (score 0):

You are, obviously, doing it the wrong way. Testing is an important part of pre-packaging. You shouldn't ignore or skip it, but rather do it the right way. Try changing the database to which it inserts the data(like test_db). It may take a while to set it up. And to make sure this database can be used forever, you should delete all the data by the end of tests. JUnit4 has annotations which make it easy for you. Use @Before, @After @Test annotations for the right methods. You need to spend sometime on it, but it will be worth it!

Comment: I think the question as well as the desire to package without running tests is perfectly valid. I don't think the OP "obviously is doing it the wrong way". Different people and projects have different needs, and these are commonly not in alignment with the Maven bible or the beliefs of various people (like yourself) about how software development should work. I think your answer would be more appreciated without its condescending approach.

Answer (score 0):

`mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true`

worked for me since the `-Dskip` did not work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

```
mvn package -Dmaven.test.skip=true
```

Answer (score -2):

The best and the easiest way to do it, in IntelliJ Idea in the window “Maven Project”, and just don’t click on the test button. I hope, I helped you. Have a good day :)

Comment: If you click package, it runs the tests, which is what OP is trying to avoid