# mvn clean install stuck when doing tests - what am i missing?

Tags: spring, maven

I want to run my app as a windows service so i modified my pom to include 
executable / true.

I tried "mvn clean install" - after a few moments, it starts doing tests but after more than 3 hours it shows only messages about websocket. I have websocket in my project, but what is the problem? Why the long running time ? Am i missing something ?

EDIT: I'm sorry about the picture, i thought the image would say more than i could say.
The only thing new about my project is the "executable - true " in the pom. I removed it and tried mvn clean install with another failure. I am thinking it has something to do with my mvn packages ? I am starting to remove them one by one to identify the source.

EDIT2: I found the source: removing websocket dependency completes mvn clean install in under 2 minutes. What is the message? Is it something wrong with my websocket ? It is the spring-boot-starter-websocket dependency.

I don't understand, why running the app in intellij works and mvn clean install doesn't ?

[image]

Comment: First do not add images to SO please add the text instead furthermore based on what should I know what you have changed in your code ? And which code? Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: I added 2 edits in which i try to explain more about the problem. It seems to be a dependency problem which i don't fully understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After simulating on a local project i believe that a local test is keeping the connection open and won't let spring finish. 
Check the test and first uncomment it to isolate the problem.

Comment: It builds but i feel that i am cheating. Something is wrong with my websocket ? I don't understand what when including websocket the building process includes those ugly and slow tests . 3 hours running and all it did was printing : "Websocketsession ... completed tasks 0, 1, 2, .. .how many more ?