# How to install a unirest with Maven?

Tags: java, maven, cmd, unirest

I am trying to install unirest-java. I'm not really familiar with cmd. so I followed their instructions step by step and then after I run the last step it fails and I don't know why it happens.

This is the link for the instructions that I have followed:
https://konghq.com/blog/installing-unirest-java-with-the-maven-assembly-plugin/

I tried also `-Denforcer.skip` besides `clean assembly:assembly`

and this was the result: (I skipped some of the first lines because I can't post it with more than 30000 characters)

````
[ERROR] Tests run: 6, Failures: 5, Errors: 0, Skipped: 1, Time elapsed: 0.018 s <<< FAILURE! - in BehaviorTests.BodyLogSummaryTest
[ERROR] forSimpleBodies  Time elapsed: 0.003 s  <<< FAILURE!
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError:
expected: <POST http://somewhere/beans?fruit=apple
Accept=image/raw
===================================
this is the body> but was: <POST http://somewhere/beans?fruit=apple
Accept=image/raw
===================================
this is the body>
        at BehaviorTests.BodyLogSummaryTest.forSimpleBodies(BodyLogSummaryTest.java:62)

[ERROR] forObjectBodies  Time elapsed: 0.001 s  <<< FAILURE!
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError:
expected: <POST http://somewhere/beans?fruit=apple
Accept=image/raw
===================================
{"bar":"zip"}> but was: <POST http://somewhere/beans?fruit=apple
Accept=image/raw
===================================
{"bar":"zip"}>
        at BehaviorTests.BodyLogSummaryTest.forObjectBodies(BodyLogSummaryTest.java:94)

[ERROR] forSimpleGets  Time elapsed: 0.001 s  <<< FAILURE!
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError:
expected: <GET http://somewhere/beans?fruit=apple
Accept=image/raw
===================================> but was: <GET http://somewhere/beans?fruit=apple
Accept=image/raw
===================================>
        at BehaviorTests.BodyLogSummaryTest.forSimpleGets(BodyLogSummaryTest.java:47)

[ERROR] forJsonBodies  Time elapsed: 0.001 s  <<< FAILURE!
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError:
expected: <POST http://somewhere/beans?fruit=apple
Accept=image/raw
===================================
{"muppet":"Gonzo"}> but was: <POST http://somewhere/beans?fruit=apple
Accept=image/raw
===================================
{"muppet":"Gonzo"}>
        at BehaviorTests.BodyLogSummaryTest.forJsonBodies(BodyLogSummaryTest.java:78)

[ERROR] simpleFormBody  Time elapsed: 0.005 s  <<< FAILURE!
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError:
expected: <POST http://somewhere/beans?fruit=apple
Accept=image/raw
===================================
album=77&band=Talking+Heads> but was: <POST http://somewhere/beans?fruit=apple
Accept=image/raw
===================================
album=77&band=Talking+Heads>
        at BehaviorTests.BodyLogSummaryTest.simpleFormBody(BodyLogSummaryTest.java:111)

[INFO] Running BehaviorTests.CachingAlternativeTest
[INFO] Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.002 s - in BehaviorTests.CachingAlternativeTest
[INFO] Running BehaviorTests.CachingTest
[INFO] Tests run: 9, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.017 s - in BehaviorTests.CachingTest
[INFO] Running BehaviorTests.CallbackFutureTest
[WARNING] Tests run: 5, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 3, Time elapsed: 0.035 s - in BehaviorTests.CallbackFutureTest
[INFO] Running BehaviorTests.CertificateTests
[WARNING] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 1, Time elapsed: 0.002 s - in BehaviorTests.CertificateTests
[INFO] Running BehaviorTests.ConsumerTest
[INFO] Tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 5.708 s - in BehaviorTests.ConsumerTest
[INFO] Running BehaviorTests.CookieTest
[INFO] Tests run: 17, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.002 s - in BehaviorTests.CookieTest
[INFO] Running BehaviorTests.CustomClientTest
[INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.18 s - in BehaviorTests.CustomClientTest
[INFO] Running BehaviorTests.CustomObjectMapperTest
[INFO] Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.023 s - in BehaviorTests.CustomObjectMapperTest
[INFO] Running BehaviorTests.DefectTest
[WARNING] Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 1, Time elapsed: 0.002 s - in BehaviorTests.DefectTest
[INFO] Running BehaviorTests.DownloadProgressTest
[INFO] Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.029 s - in BehaviorTests.DownloadProgressTest
[INFO] Running BehaviorTests.ErrorParsingTest
[INFO] Tests run: 8, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.032 s - in BehaviorTests.ErrorParsingTest
[INFO] Running BehaviorTests.FormPostingTest
[INFO] Tests run: 11, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.057 s - in BehaviorTests.FormPostingTest
[INFO] Running BehaviorTests.GenericMappingTest
[INFO] Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.003 s - in BehaviorTests.GenericMappingTest
[INFO] Running BehaviorTests.GZipTest
[INFO] Tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.023 s - in BehaviorTests.GZipTest
[INFO] Running BehaviorTests.HeaderTest
[ERROR] Tests run: 20, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 1, Time elapsed: 0.071 s <<< FAILURE! - in BehaviorTests.HeaderTest
[ERROR] unicodeBasicAuth  Time elapsed: 0 s  <<< FAILURE!
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: Expected Header Value Failed: Basic 44GT44KT44Gr44Gh44GvOuOBk+OCk+OBq+OBoeOBrw== ==> expected: <true> but was: <false>
        at BehaviorTests.HeaderTest.unicodeBasicAuth(HeaderTest.java:79)

[INFO] Running BehaviorTests.HostsHeaderTest
[WARNING] Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 1, Time elapsed: 0.002 s - in BehaviorTests.HostsHeaderTest
[INFO] Running BehaviorTests.InterceptorTest
[INFO] Tests run: 7, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.076 s - in BehaviorTests.InterceptorTest
[INFO] Running BehaviorTests.JsonPatchTest
[INFO] Tests run: 9, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.051 s - in BehaviorTests.JsonPatchTest
[INFO] Running BehaviorTests.MetricsTest
[WARNING] Tests run: 11, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 1, Time elapsed: 0.072 s - in BehaviorTests.MetricsTest
[INFO] Running BehaviorTests.MultiPartFormPostingTest
[ERROR] Tests run: 27, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.209 s <<< FAILURE! - in BehaviorTests.MultiPartFormPostingTest
[ERROR] testPostBinaryUTF8  Time elapsed: 0.006 s  <<< FAILURE!
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: Expected Query or Form value: ????? ==> expected: <true> but was: <false>
        at BehaviorTests.MultiPartFormPostingTest.testPostBinaryUTF8(MultiPartFormPostingTest.java:339)

[INFO] Running BehaviorTests.ObjectFunctionalTest
[INFO] Tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.019 s - in BehaviorTests.ObjectFunctionalTest
[INFO] Running BehaviorTests.PagingTest
[INFO] Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.021 s - in BehaviorTests.PagingTest
[INFO] Running BehaviorTests.PathParamTest
[INFO] Tests run: 11, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.035 s - in BehaviorTests.PathParamTest
[INFO] Running BehaviorTests.PostRequestHandlersTest
[INFO] Tests run: 8, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.029 s - in BehaviorTests.PostRequestHandlersTest
[INFO] Running BehaviorTests.ProxyTest
[WARNING] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 1, Time elapsed: 0.001 s - in BehaviorTests.ProxyTest
[INFO] Running BehaviorTests.QueryStringTest
[INFO] Tests run: 9, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.028 s - in BehaviorTests.QueryStringTest
[INFO] Running BehaviorTests.RawUrlTest
[INFO] Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.003 s - in BehaviorTests.RawUrlTest
[INFO] Running BehaviorTests.RedirectHandlingTest
[INFO] Tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.029 s - in BehaviorTests.RedirectHandlingTest
[INFO] Running BehaviorTests.ResponseHeaderTest
[INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.003 s - in BehaviorTests.ResponseHeaderTest
[INFO] Running BehaviorTests.ShutDownHooksTest
[ERROR] Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 2, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.002 s <<< FAILURE! - in BehaviorTests.ShutDownHooksTest
[ERROR] canAddShutdownHooks  Time elapsed: 0 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private static java.util.IdentityHashMap java.lang.ApplicationShutdownHooks.hooks accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @3e9b1010
        at BehaviorTests.ShutDownHooksTest.getShutdownHookMap(ShutDownHooksTest.java:93)
        at BehaviorTests.ShutDownHooksTest.clearUnirestHooks(ShutDownHooksTest.java:78)
        at BehaviorTests.ShutDownHooksTest.setUp(ShutDownHooksTest.java:44)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private static java.util.IdentityHashMap java.lang.ApplicationShutdownHooks.hooks accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @3e9b1010
        at BehaviorTests.ShutDownHooksTest.getShutdownHookMap(ShutDownHooksTest.java:89)
        at BehaviorTests.ShutDownHooksTest.clearUnirestHooks(ShutDownHooksTest.java:78)
        at BehaviorTests.ShutDownHooksTest.setUp(ShutDownHooksTest.java:44)

[ERROR] ifClientsAreAlreadyRunningCanAddShutdownHooks  Time elapsed: 0 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private static java.util.IdentityHashMap java.lang.ApplicationShutdownHooks.hooks accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @3e9b1010
        at BehaviorTests.ShutDownHooksTest.getShutdownHookMap(ShutDownHooksTest.java:93)
        at BehaviorTests.ShutDownHooksTest.clearUnirestHooks(ShutDownHooksTest.java:78)
        at BehaviorTests.ShutDownHooksTest.setUp(ShutDownHooksTest.java:44)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private static java.util.IdentityHashMap java.lang.ApplicationShutdownHooks.hooks accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @3e9b1010
        at BehaviorTests.ShutDownHooksTest.getShutdownHookMap(ShutDownHooksTest.java:89)
        at BehaviorTests.ShutDownHooksTest.clearUnirestHooks(ShutDownHooksTest.java:78)
        at BehaviorTests.ShutDownHooksTest.setUp(ShutDownHooksTest.java:44)

[INFO] Running BehaviorTests.TimeoutTest
[WARNING] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 1, Time elapsed: 0.005 s - in BehaviorTests.TimeoutTest
[INFO] Running BehaviorTests.UniBodyPostingTest
[ERROR] Tests run: 18, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.003 s <<< FAILURE! - in BehaviorTests.UniBodyPostingTest
[ERROR] testPostRawBody  Time elapsed: 0 s  <<< FAILURE!
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: expected: <'"@?????-test-123-0.76226762713704> but was: <'"@?????-test-123-0.76226762713704>
        at BehaviorTests.UniBodyPostingTest.testPostRawBody(UniBodyPostingTest.java:102)

[INFO] Running BehaviorTests.UploadProgressTest
[INFO] Tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.005 s - in BehaviorTests.UploadProgressTest
[INFO] Running BehaviorTests.VerbTest
[INFO] Tests run: 7, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.003 s - in BehaviorTests.VerbTest
[INFO] Running kong.unirest.apache.ApacheBehaviorTest
[INFO] Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.028 s - in kong.unirest.apache.ApacheBehaviorTest
[INFO] Running kong.unirest.apache.ApacheClientTest
[INFO] Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.011 s - in kong.unirest.apache.ApacheClientTest
[INFO] Running kong.unirest.apache.ApacheInterceptorTest
[INFO] Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.024 s - in kong.unirest.apache.ApacheInterceptorTest
[INFO] Running kong.unirest.apache.BaseApacheClientTest
[INFO] Tests run: 5, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.002 s - in kong.unirest.apache.BaseApacheClientTest
[INFO] Running kong.unirest.apache.ContentTypeTest
[INFO] Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.002 s - in kong.unirest.apache.ContentTypeTest
[INFO] Running kong.unirest.apache.ExampleCertificateTest
[WARNING] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 1, Time elapsed: 0.004 s - in kong.unirest.apache.ExampleCertificateTest
[INFO] Running kong.unirest.apache.LifeCycleTest
[INFO] Tests run: 6, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 2.854 s - in kong.unirest.apache.LifeCycleTest
[INFO] Running kong.unirest.apache.SecurityConfigTest
[INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.003 s - in kong.unirest.apache.SecurityConfigTest
[INFO] Running kong.unirest.apache.UtilTest
[INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.002 s - in kong.unirest.apache.UtilTest
[INFO] Running kong.unirest.BaseRequestTest
[INFO] Tests run: 12, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.002 s - in kong.unirest.BaseRequestTest
[INFO] Running kong.unirest.BodyTest
[INFO] Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.003 s - in kong.unirest.BodyTest
[INFO] Running kong.unirest.ByteArrayPartTest
[INFO] Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.003 s - in kong.unirest.ByteArrayPartTest
[INFO] Running kong.unirest.CacheManagerTest
[INFO] Tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.002 s - in kong.unirest.CacheManagerTest
[INFO] Running kong.unirest.ClientFactoryTest
[INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.002 s - in kong.unirest.ClientFactoryTest
[INFO] Running kong.unirest.CompoundInterceptorTest
[INFO] Tests run: 8, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.051 s - in kong.unirest.CompoundInterceptorTest
[INFO] Running kong.unirest.ConfigTest
[INFO] Tests run: 24, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.07 s - in kong.unirest.ConfigTest
[INFO] Running kong.unirest.CookieParsingTest
[INFO] Tests run: 13, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.003 s - in kong.unirest.CookieParsingTest
[INFO] Running kong.unirest.FilePartTest
[INFO] Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.002 s - in kong.unirest.FilePartTest
[INFO] Running kong.unirest.HeaderEntryTest
[INFO] Tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.002 s - in kong.unirest.HeaderEntryTest
[INFO] Running kong.unirest.HeadersTest
[INFO] Tests run: 6, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.002 s - in kong.unirest.HeadersTest
[INFO] Running kong.unirest.HttpMethodTest
[INFO] Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.003 s - in kong.unirest.HttpMethodTest
[INFO] Running kong.unirest.InputStreamPartTest
[INFO] Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.003 s - in kong.unirest.InputStreamPartTest
[INFO] Running kong.unirest.JacksonObjectMapperTest
actualStr = {"requestId":"c42b4c39-ad61-4896-ab8f-ca4db39b096c","headers":{},"files":[],"params":{},"body":null,"url":null,"queryString":null,"method":null,"routeParams":{},"contentType":null,"jsonPatches":[{"op":"add","path":"/foo","value":"bar"},{"op":"add","path":"/baz","value":"qux"}],"status":null,"cookies":{}}
[INFO] Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.014 s - in kong.unirest.JacksonObjectMapperTest
[INFO] Running kong.unirest.json.JSONArrayTest
[INFO] Tests run: 38, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.003 s - in kong.unirest.json.JSONArrayTest
[INFO] Running kong.unirest.json.JSONObjectTest
[ERROR] Tests run: 55, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.002 s <<< FAILURE! - in kong.unirest.json.JSONObjectTest
[ERROR] stringToValue  Time elapsed: 0 s  <<< FAILURE!
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: Wrong Error Message ==> expected: <null> but was: <Cannot invoke "String.contentEquals(java.lang.CharSequence)" because "str" is null>
        at kong.unirest.json.JSONObjectTest.stringToValue(JSONObjectTest.java:559)

[INFO] Running kong.unirest.json.JSONPointerTest
[INFO] Tests run: 23, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.003 s - in kong.unirest.json.JSONPointerTest
[INFO] Running kong.unirest.JsonNodeTest
[INFO] Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.002 s - in kong.unirest.JsonNodeTest
[INFO] Running kong.unirest.JsonObjectMapperTest
[INFO] Tests run: 27, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.002 s - in kong.unirest.JsonObjectMapperTest
[INFO] Running kong.unirest.JsonPatchItemTest
[INFO] Tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.002 s - in kong.unirest.JsonPatchItemTest
[INFO] Running kong.unirest.PagedListTest
[INFO] Tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.002 s - in kong.unirest.PagedListTest
[INFO] Running kong.unirest.ParamPartTest
[INFO] Tests run: 5, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.001 s - in kong.unirest.ParamPartTest
[INFO] Running kong.unirest.PathTest
[INFO] Tests run: 5, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.001 s - in kong.unirest.PathTest
[INFO] Running kong.unirest.ResponseUtilsTest
[INFO] Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.002 s - in kong.unirest.ResponseUtilsTest
[INFO] Running kong.unirest.UnibodyStringTest
[INFO] Tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.002 s - in kong.unirest.UnibodyStringTest
[INFO] Running kong.unirest.UniByteArrayBodyTest
[INFO] Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.002 s - in kong.unirest.UniByteArrayBodyTest
[INFO] Running kong.unirest.UriFormatterTest
[INFO] Tests run: 5, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.002 s - in kong.unirest.UriFormatterTest
[Thread-9] INFO io.javalin.Javalin - Stopping Javalin ...
[Thread-9] INFO io.javalin.Javalin - Javalin has stopped
[INFO]
[INFO] Results:
[INFO]
[ERROR] Failures:
[ERROR]   BodyLogSummaryTest.forJsonBodies:78 expected: <POST http://somewhere/beans?fruit=apple
Accept=image/raw
===================================
{"muppet":"Gonzo"}> but was: <POST http://somewhere/beans?fruit=apple
Accept=image/raw
===================================
{"muppet":"Gonzo"}>
[ERROR]   BodyLogSummaryTest.forObjectBodies:94 expected: <POST http://somewhere/beans?fruit=apple
Accept=image/raw
===================================
{"bar":"zip"}> but was: <POST http://somewhere/beans?fruit=apple
Accept=image/raw
===================================
{"bar":"zip"}>
[ERROR]   BodyLogSummaryTest.forSimpleBodies:62 expected: <POST http://somewhere/beans?fruit=apple
Accept=image/raw
===================================
this is the body> but was: <POST http://somewhere/beans?fruit=apple
Accept=image/raw
===================================
this is the body>
[ERROR]   BodyLogSummaryTest.forSimpleGets:47 expected: <GET http://somewhere/beans?fruit=apple
Accept=image/raw
===================================> but was: <GET http://somewhere/beans?fruit=apple
Accept=image/raw
===================================>
[ERROR]   BodyLogSummaryTest.simpleFormBody:111 expected: <POST http://somewhere/beans?fruit=apple
Accept=image/raw
===================================
album=77&band=Talking+Heads> but was: <POST http://somewhere/beans?fruit=apple
Accept=image/raw
===================================
album=77&band=Talking+Heads>
[ERROR]   HeaderTest.unicodeBasicAuth:79 Expected Header Value Failed: Basic 44GT44KT44Gr44Gh44GvOuOBk+OCk+OBq+OBoeOBrw== ==> expected: <true> but was: <false>
[ERROR]   MultiPartFormPostingTest.testPostBinaryUTF8:339 Expected Query or Form value: ????? ==> expected: <true> but was: <false>
[ERROR]   UniBodyPostingTest.testPostRawBody:102 expected: <'"@?????-test-123-0.76226762713704> but was: <'"@?????-test-123-0.76226762713704>
[ERROR]   JSONObjectTest.stringToValue:559 Wrong Error Message ==> expected: <null> but was: <Cannot invoke "String.contentEquals(java.lang.CharSequence)" because "str" is null>
[ERROR] Errors:
[ERROR]   ShutDownHooksTest.setUp:44->clearUnirestHooks:78->getShutdownHookMap:93 Runtime
[ERROR]   ShutDownHooksTest.setUp:44->clearUnirestHooks:78->getShutdownHookMap:93 Runtime
[INFO]
[ERROR] Tests run: 571, Failures: 9, Errors: 2, Skipped: 12
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary for unirest 3.11.12-SNAPSHOT:
[INFO]
[INFO] unirest ............................................ FAILURE [ 25.152 s]
[INFO] unirest-java ....................................... SUCCESS [  0.018 s]
[INFO] unirest-objectmappers-gson ......................... SUCCESS [  0.018 s]
[INFO] unirest-objectmapper-jackson ....................... SUCCESS [  0.014 s]
[INFO] unirest-mocks ...................................... SUCCESS [  0.017 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  26.175 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-07-04T15:33:22+03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test (default-test) on project unirest-java: There are test failures.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Please refer to C:\Users\Redwan\unirest-java\unirest\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date].dump, [date]-jvmRun[N].dump and [date].dumpstream.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
[ERROR]
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <args> -rf :unirest-java```
````

Answer (score 1):

The 'proper' way would probably be to fix the issues raised in the CVEs by upping the version numbers of the components in question in pom.xml.
The dirty way would be to disable security checking, though I'm not sure how.

CVE-2021-28169
CVE-2021-28169
CVE-2021-28169
CVE-2021-34428
CVE-2021-34428
CVE-2021-34428

Comment: I have no idea how to upper the version numbers.

Answer (score 1):

The build is failing because the [`BanVulnerableDependencies`](https://sonatype.github.io/ossindex-maven/enforcer-rules/) [rule for `maven-enforcer-plugin`](https://github.com/Kong/unirest-java/blob/b1ca68f7d8ed2b7868f9787f9794912c84e02704/pom.xml#L313) is checking whether any artifacts have known vulnerabilities.

This project is using a version of `jetty-server` (`9.4.39.v20210325`) with several CVEs recorded against it.

To make progress, bump the version to the latest release (currently, `9.4.42.v20210604` as a patch release, or `11.0.5` overall). This doesn't appear to be a direct dependency, so you'll need to [identify how it's being brought in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6110782/how-can-i-view-transitive-dependencies-of-a-maven-pom-xml-file).

Alternatively, build with `-Denforcer.skip` to skip these checks.

Edit: with the Enforcer checks skipped, you're now seeing that the tests are also failing:

```
[ERROR] Tests run: 571, Failures: 9, Errors: 2, Skipped: 12
```

you can always [build and skip tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7456006/maven-package-install-without-test-skip-tests), but these are problems that need to be fixed in the project.

Comment: I did the `Denforcer.skip` but still get an error. updated the post for the error messages